# Redirect all www and http ==>> non www https on AWS Elastic Beanstalk with Load Balancer

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I currently have this in place to redirect all `http` traffic to `https`.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !=https
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The above is working OK.

Now I'm trying to add rewrite condition to force all `https://www` traffic to `https` without the `www`.

Please note that this is an AWS Elastic Beanstalk running Apache behind Elastic Load Balancer

=============================

EDIT:

**Working code:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !=https [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^(www\.)?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ https://%2/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this rule instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^(www\.)?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ https://%2/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately it is not working as all traffic is redirected to `https://www.` and the server/domain missing. I think it has something to do with the AWS load balancer X-Forward-Proto

Comment: @WayBehind whoops, that `%1` is supposed to be `%2`

Comment: Thanks again! Unfortunately this time we have `"This webpage has a redirect loop"` and the `server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete`.

Comment: @WayBehind you sure you don't have something else that's redirecting somewhere? those rules won't cause a loop unless something else is either redirecting back to have the "www" or non-SSL

Comment: Jon, no I dont have there anything else as this is the only redirect in place. Again, I think it may have something to do with their load balancer headers `X-Forwarded-Proto`

Comment: @WayBehind oh that's right, meant to say that you should replace the `%{HTTPS} off` part with your line: `%{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !=https` (though there needs to be that `[OR]`)

Comment: Thanks. Almost there. The only redirect that doesnt work from this rewrite is `https://www` to `https` without www. It will still give me `https://www./` without the domain/server value

Comment: Discard the above. It actually works! IT was just a cached page! Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Actually `RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} ^http$ [OR]` would be better because `!=https` fails the ELB health checking. So the full working answer is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} ^http$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^(www\.)?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ https://%2/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks! I will give it a shot!

Answer (score 2):

To also take into account the ELB health check use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !=https [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !ELB-HealthChecker
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^(www\.)?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ https://%2/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for anyone looking for a full copy and paste solution using ElasticBeanstalks config files.

1. Create file inside `.ebextensions/`, lets call it `01-https.config`.
2. Add the following:

```
files:
  "/etc/httpd/conf.d/http-redirect.conf":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [OR,NC]
      RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
      RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !ELB-HealthChecker
      RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI}
```

This takes into consideration ELB health check and will work for the following examples:

- http://example.com
- http://www.example.com
- https://www.example.com

which will be redirected to https://example.com